# CLI communication with already running Java application?

Tags: java, command-line, ipc

When **starting** a application, one can pass parameters to the application. But how can one pass parameters to a **already running** (Java) application / how can I handle such cases in my Java program?

In other words: How can I communicate from a .bat file / CLI processes with a already running Java application? Note that both things (CLI stuff and Java application) are my own applications and I can adapt the source code - I just don't know how ;-)

Comment: *"how can one pass parameters to a already running (Java) application"*  One way is to create a GUI with input areas and other controls.

Comment: Unfortunately I need batch integration and in that case a GUI is a bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using socket for cross platform IPC, with help of [`Apache thrift`](http://thrift.apache.org/) . You can implement RPC method to use from CLI utility.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't it possible to call a running ajva application again with new parameters and instead of running the application again, just react to the new command lien parameters?

Comment: of course you can, by combine utility function to your application, such as `main` method check if there's already run instance, connect to it pre-define CLI listen socket, send to the command to process.

Comment: Thanks for the reference on Apache Thrift. This could be quite useful to me and could simplify quite a bit of my work. +1.

Comment: Thinking about it, it amkes sense one needs sth. external like sockets. I ended up using FileSystem, in Java 7 there are the file system watchers, just echo sth. from the cli to a text file and parse it using your java application. quite easy. even easier: monitor a folder, create one file for one command/passing argument etc.